# How to pass down listing of files in directory from PHP to Android/Java

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to download all the images in a directory from my web site to my Android phone and am having trouble figuring out the best way to go about this.  I currently have a php function:

```
} else if( $_REQUEST['funName'] == "getFullSizeImagesList" ) {
    $target_path_fullsize  = "../blacktie/images/fullsize/";
    $fullSize = scandir($target_path_fullsize);
    $fullSize_sliced = array_slice($fullSize, 2);

    print(json_encode($fullSize_sliced));
}
```

This gives me the following result that I can read using android:

> ["123.jpg", "456.jpg"]

I could easily parse this string into an array but I am worried that the list will eventually get very large and I don't want to incur that overhead.  Is there a better way to do this in PHP.

I was also wondering if it would be a good idea to just use the phone to look up the directory and pull down the contents, bypassing the PHP code.  I am also going to eventually implement this on the iPHone so I am wondering if this second option would work better in the long term.

Can someone please give me some advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If list of files is going to get bigger you can limit number of images in your response. 
For example you can have response like this:

```
{
     currentPage: 1,
     totalPages: 12,
     images: ["123.jpg", "456.jpg"]
}
```

and in each request you can specify which page you are requesting. Another solution is to specify in request number of pictures you are requesting.

Comment: O yea I didn't even think about that.  That's a pretty good idea.  I'll have to think about this a little more.  Thanks!